# Changing field to required throws ExpressionChangedAfterCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to make a field required on the click of a button. When I try and change the field to required I get this error:

```
core.js:6406 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'disabled': 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
```

Here is my controller code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.exportTypeForm = new FormGroup({
    exportType: new FormControl('page', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('')
  });
}

onExportTypeChange(e: MatRadioChange): void {
  if (e.value === 'list') {
    this.exportTypeForm.controls['email'].setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.exportTypeForm.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.showEmailField = true;
  } else {
    this.exportTypeForm.controls['email'].clearValidators();
    this.exportTypeForm.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.showEmailField = false;
  }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<form *ngIf="exportTypeForm" [formGroup]="exportTypeForm">
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="exportType" (change)="onExportTypeChange($event)">
    <mat-radio-button value="page">This page</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="ml-4" value="list">All pages</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="showEmailField" class="mb-4">
    <mat-label>Email Address</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="email" />
    <mat-hint>An email with a link to the excel file will be sent to this address</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I am not sure of any other way to do this. Can someone help me find a way to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried moving your logic in the `ngOnInit` to a `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: Did you try using `ChangeDetectorRef`? https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that it was because of how I was running the logic on the `updateValueAndValidity()` method. I was calling it on the whole form, which doesn't work. You need to call it on the individual control.

Here is working code:

```
onExportTypeChange(e: MatRadioChange): void {
  if (e.value === 'list') {
    this.exportTypeForm.get('email').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.exportTypeForm.get('email').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.showEmailField = true;
  } else {
    this.exportTypeForm.get('email').clearValidators();
    this.exportTypeForm.get('email').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.showEmailField = false;
  }
}
```